# While loop to retrieve input, not working correct in C

Tags: c, input, while-loop, hex

I have a problem when using a user input method which allow validates the input.
I require to return the input after its been validated.

```
char* getvalidinputnumber(int length, char prompt[],int base)
    {
        char* user_input = calloc(length+1,sizeof(char));

        fflush(stdin);
        fflush(FILE *);

        /*Prompts & Gets the users input and saves it in user_input*/
        do {
            printf("\n %s", prompt); 
            fgets(user_input,length+1,stdin); 
            /*printf("\n##Entered %s : ", user_input);*/
        } while(!isnumeric(user_input,base) && strlen(user_input) != length);

        fflush(stdin); 
        return(user_input);
    }
```

When calling this function within my main like....

```
while (strcmp(user_input,"00000000") != 0)
{
    user_input = getvalidinputnumber(8, "Enter HEX Value",16);
}
```

It also does the following ...

> Enter HEX Value
>
> Enter HEX Value

Twice rather than just once and when i enter a hex value it returns the hex correct but then runs twice again ive tryed using fflush but this doesnt seem to solve it.

How could i solve this or is there a better way to get the input for example using scanf?

Comment: `fflush(FILE *);`? What is that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by flushing `stdin`?

Comment: try to remove your "fflush(stdin)". You can check some alternatives here: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/50037-alternative-fflush-stdin.html

Comment: You have a memory leak in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fflush(stdin)
```

Causes an Undefined Behavior! `fflush()` should only be used on streams open for output, not input.

Comment: So whats an alternative method?

Comment: @user983969: There is no portable solution really.There can be multiple options, you might just do a google search and it will give you a bunch of them.

Comment: Scanf seems to work on current pc , not to sure about linux as fgets didnt have this error in linux